# 95 Toyota Tacoma 4x4 Clutch Staying Engaged

Tags: toyota, clutch, tacoma

I had my clutch repaired almost a year ago. But I have not been the regular driver of the truck. As I went to drive it a week ago I noticed that the clutch is staying engaged while the pedal is being pressed, causing the truck to stall. I checked the fluid and it is full. Why is this happening?

Comment: More than likely the clutch hydraulics need to be bled.